# Existence of a integral

Tags: calculus

Let us assume $s,p:[0,t]\to(-\infty,0]$ and $A\geq \frac{B}{2}>0$, $D\geq 0$ are constant. Now consider the integral $$\int_{s}^0\frac{1}{\sqrt{4D+4Ap+B(1-e^{2p})}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2p}}}\ dp.$$
It has given that $0<4D+4As+B(1-e^{2s})$ and one can easily show that $4D+4As+B(1-e^{2s})<4D$.

Since $H(s)=4D+4As+B(1-e^{2s})$ is increasing with respect to $s$ for $s<0$. We have $H(0)=4D$. Can it be possible to show that the integral exists?

We already know that $\int_{s}^0 \frac{dp}{\sqrt{1-e^{2p}}}$ exists but $\int_{s}^0 \frac{dp}{1-e^{2p}}$ does not exists. Any idea how to show that our integral exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, we have
$F^{\prime}(t)=4A-2 Be^{2t}\geq 4A-2B\geq 0$ by the assumption $A\geq B/2$ and the fact that $e^{t}\leq 1$ for all $t\leq 0$.
So, $F$ is increasing on $[s,0]$. Therefore, for each $s\leq 0$  we have
$F(0)\geq F(t)\geq F(s)>0$ for all $s\leq t\leq 0$. This implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt{F(0)}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{F(t)}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{F(s)}}$ and your integrand satisfies
$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{F(t)}}\right| \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2t}}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{F(s)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2t}}}$$
and the latter is integrable in $t$ 0n $]-\infty,0]$.

Comment: When $s:[0,T]\to (-\infty,0] $ is a function, is the same arguments follows there?

Comment: If $s$ is a function of $t$ then the answer is" no, not necessarily". If you receive an answer to your question that you understand and find correct, you should accept it by checking the tick sign.

Answer (score 1):

We have $F(t) \gt 0$ for $s \leq t \leq 0$

And also note that $F(t)$ is continuous in the domain $s \leq t \leq 0$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{F(t)} \;\mathrm{is\;continuous} $$
As $F(t)$ is non zero for $s \leq t \leq 0$ ,we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{F(t)}}$ is continuous
$$ \Rightarrow \int^0_s \frac{1}{\sqrt{F(t)}}dx \;\mathrm{Exists}$$